# Creating calculated measure on a measure by relating it with another measure

Tags: ssas, mdx

I need to create calculated measure on a measure by relating with another measure, to explain the scenario i am taking a typical marks and subjects example.

Consider there are 2 measure groups one is Subject Facts, Mark Facts and 1 dimension Subject Dim.

Subject Facts measure groups contains Subjects Count (all subjects count), Science Subjects Count (only science subjects count)
Mark Facts contains one measure Marks

Subject Dimension contains Subject ID dim

Now i need to create calculated measure using Marks measure which gives only science subject marks

PS: When i drag subject dim on rows and subject measures on columns, subjects count measures is 1 for all subjects and science subjects count is 0 or 1 (This is how the relation exists)

Can anyone please help me in creating calculated measure

Comment: I'm not sure why you need a calculated measure.  If your hierarchy has a dimension called [Subject] then you could have category for dept type.  Then you'd just need to use [Subject].[Sciences].Children to get all the sciences.

Comment: @Jesse: In my case there is no such dimension available and the example i took here for simplicity in understanding :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for this.

```
[Measure].[Science Marks] AS SUM(FILTER([Subject Dim].MEMBERS,[Measures].[Subjects Count]>0),[Measures].[Subjects Marks])
```